# How can I future-proof the `round` function in Python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, future-proof

When `round` is imported from the future, it does not behave the same as the Python3 `round` function. Specifically, it does not support negative digit rounding.

In Python3:

```
>>> round(4781, -2)
4800
```

In Python2:

```
>>> from builtins import round
>>> round(4781, -2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future/builtins/newround.py", line 33, in newround
    raise NotImplementedError('negative ndigits not supported yet')
NotImplementedError: negative ndigits not supported yet
```

Possible solutions include error handling for negative rounding, writing my own `round` function, etc. How should this be handled? (Implicitly, I'm asking for best practices, most Pythonic, accepted by community, etc.)

Comment: `from builtins import round` doesn't work for me in Python 2, gives me `ImportError: No module named builtins`. I also can't find it in the documentation. Did you do something special to make that work? If so, what?

Comment: @StefanPochmann That comes from the future package I assume http://python-future.org/index.html

Comment: I did not do anything "special". The statement worked as shown. You could try `from future.builtins import round`.

Comment: The most pythonic solution would probably be to drop Python 2...

Answer (score 3):

I was going to suggest your custom function idea so you can ensure it always does what you want, but this appears to be a special (weird) case where if I *don't* use `future.builtin.round()` I get

Python 3.6:

```
>>> round(4781, -2)
4800
```

and Python 2.7:

```
>>> round(4781, -2)
4800.0
```

It appears to just be the `future.builtins` that is somehow broken; in this case, you should avoid using the `future.builtins.round()` function. Note that py3 `round()` returns an integer while py2 `round()` returns a float, but that seems to be the only difference between the two stock implementations (for simple rounding operations such as the examples given).

Comment: There are other differences between py2 and py3, such as [Banker's Rounding](http://python-future.org/future-builtins.html). So I don't think I can just *not* import `round` from the future, because I would have to account for several differences to future-proof my code: different return type, as you point out, and different rounding behavior.

Comment: Good point. I was referring to just the example given and other simple rounding, but you're absolutely right. I edited my answer to clarify.